# PHP: include inside include

Tags: php

In dbc.php I have where the connection to the mysql db gets made, and all my functions is there.

dbc.php is included on all my files.

Now all functions are in dbc.php and i would like to sort out alittle. I was thinking about putting all form_*() functions to form_api.php, and then include it in dbc.php. But will this work? Can i just include inside a file i included? Or should i use require/include_once ?

help me out thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes .... that is perfectly permissible.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [__autoload()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) method for your libraries and put them in to classes.

Comment: Great advice! Will result in yet another application build of static methods.

Comment: wish I knew how.. Could you give me an example on how to use this method to include functions

Comment: @Karem: Don't. Not now. Learn to walk before you learn to run.

Comment: @Mchl I don't see anything wrong with wrapping similar methods in to classes, that would make application code at least more organised and easier to optimise.

Comment: @Karem on autoload page there are plenty examples on possible usage, on how classes works you can find here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 0):

It should work, just save the form_api.php file in the same folder as your dbc.php file and include it from it. As you probably know, include_once() has the same behaviour but includes a file just once, no matter how many times you try to include it, so it is perfectly OK to use include_once instead of include(). require() will stop the execution will a fatal error if the file can't be included for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use include() functions at included pages. So your first questions answer is YES .

And now 2. question. Actually , there is an different between **include** and **include_once** .

```
include("dbc.php");
include("dbc.php");
include("dbc.php");
// dbc.php will include 3 times .

include_once("dbc.php");
include_once("dbc.php");
include_once("dbc.php");
// dbc.php will include 1 time
```

So, i prefer include_once :)